# Convert Visual C++ code to Borland C++Builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, webbrowser-control, c++builder, vcl

I have coded a program with Visual C++. But now I must put my code in a program which is coded with Borland C++Builder. I have a WebBrowser item on my form. In Visual C++, I write data to a textbox, get data from the textbox, and click a button on the WebBrowser with this code:

Write Data:

```
WebBrowser1->Document->GetElementById("okul_kod")->SetAttribute("value", TextBox2->Text);
```

Get Data:

```
textBox17->Text = WebBrowser1->Document->GetElementById("kay_cev")->GetAttribute("value");
```

Button Click:

```
WebBrowser1->Document->GetElementById("panelden_kayit")->InvokeMember("click");
```

I tried lots of things, and searched online, but I can't find how to convert this code to Borland C++Builder.

Can you please give me a clue or advice?

Comment: I  can advise you not to waste your time with Borland C++.

Comment: You are right, but we have a big project coded with Borland C++ 10 years ago. And now we have to add some changes to it.

Comment: @Rose_The_Only *And now we have to add some changes to it* -- Was this not part of your research or planning phase when discussing this with your project leader(s) and other programmers?  Even adding to Visual C++ projects written 10 years ago can be difficult as it is.

Comment: I have converted lots of code pieces to C++ but fail to convert these 3 code pieces. Then i wonder if anyone good at C++ can help me or tells a way to go..

Comment: Good at C++ can't help you much here. You most likely need someone good with VCL, Borland's GUI toolkit. This is as likely to come from a Delphi programmer as a C++ programmer. Adding VCL tag to see if we can get their attention.

Comment: @Rose_The_Only -- C++ isn't the issue.  You want someone to figure out one API and convert it to another API.  Maybe it's time to consider using a cross-platform browser toolkit.  This should have been part of your overall plan if you have to maintain both codebases (old Borland, new Visual C++).

Comment: @user4581301 "*Adding VCL tag to see if we can get their attention*" - you got someone's attention :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Somehow this does not surprise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++Builder 6, its `TCppWebBrowser` VCL component is a *thin* wrapper for Internet Explorer's ActiveX control.  Its `Document` property returns an `IDispatch` that you can use to gain access to IE's raw DOM interfaces directly (whereas Visual C++ appears to have wrapped those interfaces a little more nicely for you).

Try something like this:

```
#include <mshtml.h>
#include <utilcls.h>

// helpers for interface reference counting
// could alternatively use TComInterface instead of DelphiInterface
typedef DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument3> _di_IHTMLDocument3;
typedef DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement> _di_IHTMLElement;

...

// Write Data:
_di_IHTMLDocument3 doc = CppWebBrowser1->Document;
_di_IHTMLElement elem;
OleCheck(doc->getElementById(WideString("okul_kod"), &elem));
if (elem) OleCheck(elem->setAttribute(WideString("value"), TVariant(Edit2->Text)));

// Get Data:
_di_IHTMLDocument3 doc = CppWebBrowser1->Document;
_di_IHTMLElement elem;
OleCheck(doc->getElementById(WideString("kay_cev"), &elem));
TVariant value;
if (elem) OleCheck(elem->getAttribute(WideString("value"), 2, &value));
Edit17->Text = value;

//Button Click:
_di_IHTMLDocument3 doc = CppWebBrowser1->Document;
_di_IHTMLElement elem;
OleCheck(doc->getElementById(WideString("panelden_kayit"), &elem));
if (elem) elem->click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried your code. But compiler says: Undefined symbol '_di_IHTMLDocument3'

Comment: Im using Borland C++ Builder 6. I will try _di_IHTMLDocument2 and share the result. Thanks so much for your care...

Comment: Unfortunaltely IHTMLDocument2 causes the same error :(

Comment: @Rose_The_Only I use C++Builder 6 and I know for a fact that `IHTMLDocument2` works in it,I've used it many times. I will update my answer with an example shortly

Comment: thank you alot. Just a little example that writes data, reads data from textbox on webbrowser and clicks the button will extremly help me.

Comment: I tried many times and now it says: Cannot create instance of abstract class 'IHTMLDocument2'

Comment: And more info: when i include mshtml on .h file it says: [C++ Error] Unit47.h(7): E2209 Unable to open include file 'mshtml.hpp'

Comment: @Rose_The_Only I updated my answer with code that works. And it turns out that `mshtml.h` in C++Builder 6 does have `IHTMLDocument3` defined